# Petroleum engineer want Electrical engineer help?

Tags: motor, electrical

I need your help since I'm not electrical engineer :( . I'm petroleum engineer and I'm building a system to do an experiment.

The system consist of five cell (40 ml) and inside each cell a ball. 
These balls must move from side to side. These cells will be mounted on plate and this plate will swing on axis to move the ball. The swing movement is about 45 degree from each side (90 degree total).

Now, I need motor to create this movement.

First option: I'm thinking of using one motor on one side that can change (or reverse) its rotation from side to side after X seconds.

Second option: Or instead of that, use two motors. each one on one side and connector them by rope that pass by the plate. When one of them operate, the second will be switch off and so on.

I don't know which option is better or which motor should I used. For the second option, its possible to be done in the first place ?

Could you, please, help me ?

Comment: It sounds like you want a single motor with a mechanism similar to a car windscreen wiper.

Comment: I second the eccentric tappet idea. It's dead-simple, it's something you can build on your own and it's going to be more robust than any electronics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is mechanical engineering.  I suggest the general engineering stack, if it still exists.

Comment: Look into stepper motors with position control

Comment: Look for egg's mover used in the incubator. It moves eggs as you intend to move balls. You can find on poultry junkyard.

Comment: here it is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw-QKToDMVY

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a single motor and a mechanical arrangement utilising some kind of 'cam' would work far better and be more reproducible and reliable than a rope or other based mechanism.

If different ranges of motion are required or the range is critical, to avoid having to design everything mechanically I would, depending upon load (including plate) utilizing a stepper motor or servo.

Is this for mixing by any chance? 
If you did not need to tilt and the samples were not effected by magnetic fields, you could use two electromagnets per vessel and 'drag' the ball across by alternately switching on the magnets, negating the need for mechanical design and simplifying the electrical design somewhat.

A picture / more detailed description of what you want to achieve would be helpful, especially if construction has already begun.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a four bar linkage mechanism:

[image]

If you need a slow speed and low torque, then the simplest solution is to use synchronous motor with reducer, like old washing machines clock mechanism. Google: Synchronous AC Geared Motor

[image]